# General debugging

Tags: php, mysql

I have code that echoes out someone's first name and it works with some id's but not with others. Here is the code:

```
$sid = $_SESSION['id'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$sid'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$fname = $row['fname'];
.
.
.
<?php echo $fname; ?>'s Profile
```

Any idea how this can work only some of the time? I am using PHP with MySQL. I echoed out $sid and it is giving the right id.

Comment: Add a `or die(mysql_error())` after your query, run against the broken ids and you'll probably figure it out. Also, as always: [Please, don't use `mysql_* functions` in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the deprecation process has begun on it.

Comment: Ok will change to PDO or mysqli. Added the die and no errors

Comment: If there's no error how about a `print_r($row)` to assure the array has a value at the `fname` index?

Comment: Please learn about how to use parametrized queries.  The code you have now leaves you open to SQL injection.  http://bobby-tables.com/php.html has examples that I've culled from around SO.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking if the query is returning any result.

Do a check first:

```
if ($sql) { // the query worked,
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $fname = $row['fname'];
        ....
    }
}else {
    .. there was an error ...
    echo "Error: ".mysql_error();
}
```

You can do a `var_dump($row)` to see the content.

Comment: You can do a `var_dump($row)` to see the content.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the value IS coming from the database column and contains an empty string or is NULL. You should examine the database directly with a specific id to determine what to expect SPECIFICALLY.

That would explain your results.